# How do I set a default value for a new column using EF6 migrations?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, default-value, entity-framework-migrations

I know that you can manually manipulate the EF generated migration file to add in the 'defaultValue: 1' parameter to the 'AddColumn' method, but it does not seem to be generating the correct Oracle translation when I look at the generated script.

See my EF migration 'Up' method below:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("TABLE", "NEW_COLUMN", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0, defaultValue: 1));
    }
```

And after running 'update-database -script' I get the following corresponding SQL line:

```
alter table "TABLE" add ("NEW_COLUMN" number(10, 0) not null)
```

Running this against the database will not set the default value of the existing rows to the desired value of 1... What am I missing here?

I am using EF version 6.0.0.0 and Oracle Managed Data Access version 6.121.2.0

Comment: Looks like the oracle query provider simply [doesn't support it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35205502/861716).

Comment: Yep, I just came across that SO question. Luckily I found a terrible workaround. Thanks, @GertArnold.

Comment: Terrible or not, may be worth sharing.

Comment: I provided a workaround in the following SO question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205502/ef6-oracle-default-value-for-a-column-in-code-first-migration/36070053

Hopefully this helps anyone with the same issue.